# Anti Hermitian Operator

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am required to show that the operator $\partial_t$ is Anti-Hermitian. This operator is defined such that

$$\partial_t: s(t) \rightarrow \partial_t s(t) $$

Where the definition of an Anti-Hermitian operator in terms of the inner product is

$$<s_1, As_2> = - <As_1, s_2>$$

using this definition of the inner product:

$$<s_1, s_2> = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} s_1(t)[s_2(t)]^{*}dt$$

where $^{*}$ denotes the conjugate. This is probably quite a simple question (I am told) but I can't quite seem to make it make much sense. Is it a matter of using integration by parts? I tried but couldn't get the negative sign to appear from anywhere. Maybe I'm slightly confused about the purpose of the complex conjugate in these Fourier transforms.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply using integration by parts. Note that boundary terms must vanish otherwise the integral wouldn't converge. Then note that the derivative commutes with conjugation.

Comment: He means $\left(\overline{s(t)}\right)' =\overline{s'(t)}$.

Comment: Okay so $u = s_1(t) \rightarrow du = \partial_{t}s_1(t)$ and then $dv = \partial_t[s_2(t)]^{*}dt $.  But how do you integrate the $dv$? Are there plus and minus infinity bounds on the integral?

Comment: You simply remove the \partial. As I had said, the boundary terms vanish otherwise the integral wouldn't converge.

Comment: That's what integration by parts is. What's the anti-derivative of a derivative?

Comment: and then $uv - \int vdu = s_1(t)s_2(t)^{*} - \int s_2(t)^{*}\partial_{t} s_1(t) dt$

Comment: That's almost right, make sure you include the limits of integration!

Comment: ... and those limits make the $\int vdu$ part equal to the negative inner product I'm after? But what about the $s_1(t)s_2(t)$ part that's still hanging about?

Comment: As I said, make sure to include the limits of integration! That INCLUDES the part that's still hanging about.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty slow... I've wound up getting: $$<s_1(t), \partial_{t}s_2(t)> = s_1(t)s_2(t) - <\partial_{t}s_1(t), s_2(t)$$

Comment: Again what are the limits of integration? You aren't taking an indefinite integral, correct? You are integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ correct? What can $s_1(\infty)$ be?

Comment: In order for the original integral to converge (which it does by assumption), what does $s_1(\infty)$ have to be?

Comment: That's (one of) the limits of integration, as you had said.

Comment: You apply the bounds to the $s_1(t)s_2(t)^{*}$ as well.

Comment: If you are integrating with respect to t, how can you end up with leftover t? The statement of ibp includes applying bounds to the extra part.

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegrationByParts.aspx look at "Integration by parts, definite integrals"

Comment: Of course. :) So using the limits, and noting that $s_{1,2}(\pm \infty)=0$, what do you get?

Comment: AHA! I simply never learnt that aspect of by parts. What a fool I've been. I see it all now, thanks so much !

Comment: Hi! The shear number of comments in this thread triggered a system flag. It seems to me that William now understands the argument. Therefore I have mild suggestions/requests: 1) avid19 could now add some of those details to the answer (+1 in advance). I very much approve of the style to first post the *punchline* only, and add details in the comments, no argument there, but now you may consider cleaning it up. 2) Do consider deleting those comments that have now served their purpose. This is just a suggestion - not an order :-)